# How to repair the system

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-gnome

I have removed some packages thinking that they are unnecessary to me such as gimp some other, but after I have removed them suddenly my wifi stopped working also I am not able to connect to internet, I think that I might have removed some network files :( not sure

Is there a way to fix my system I mean get the necessary files back ??

I can re-install Ubuntu by backing up my data but I will be loosing all the new applications that I have installed and also I need to configure the system again which consumes a lot of time

Is there a way that I could get the removed packages without having to re-install, ie it would be better I could download all the necessary packages in tar.gz file and install them from pen drive

Please help me :)

I am using 14.04 ubuntu-gnome

Comment: you cant repair system unless you install those lost packages again

Comment: @edwardtorvalds can you say which of them are important so that I will get the tar.gz files and install them. here are some of them  ibus etc ..

Answer (score 1):

you cant repair system unless you install those lost packages again
First step is to see whether re-installing Unity helps, because it contains all default applications that comes when you install fresh ubuntu

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install unity
>
> sudo shutdown -r now

note this will require to restart your computer.
even this does not helps then you can install these network-manager software from Ubuntu Software center.

1. Network (network-manager-gnome)
2. Network (unity-control-center)

you need to reinstall the software that you have installed to share internet thru wifi

*this should work,if not then comment !*

Comment: I think that I need internet connection to do so which I don't have in the system I have deleted them

Comment: @vidhan then download deb file of those two packages from some else's computer

Comment: I am right now using ubuntu-gnome and I have unity to be my desktop background :(

Comment: I am downloading and installing all the packages that I have removed by seeing them from the /var/log/apt/history.log